# Add drag & drop to a TextArea in a PopUp window

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

I have created a ResizeableTitleWindow class which extends Titlewindow (to make it resizeable). Inside the RTW I add a TextArea and display the RTW as a PopUp. How do I add drag&drop to the TextArea?

```
public function createPopUpEdit():void {
var rtw:ResizableTitleWindow = new ResizableTitleWindow();
var st:TextArea = new TextArea();
rtw.addElement(st);
PopUpManager.addPopUp(rtw, this, false);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(rtw);
```

Usually you do this by setting properties in the .mxml file:

```
<s:TextArea id="st"
            dropEnabled="true"
            dragOver="onlyAllowCopyDragOverHandler(event)"
            dragDrop="myComponent_dragDropHandler(event)"
...
```

But in this case st is not defined in the mxml, but created with "new":

```
var st:TextArea=new TextArea();
```

I want to do  something like this in my createPopUpEdit function:

```
st.dropEnabled="true";
st.dragOver="onlyAllowCopyDragOverHandler(event)";
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Write following code. Hope it will help you.

```
            private var st:TextArea;
            private var rtw:TitleWindow;

            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                    rtw = new TitleWindow();
                    st = new TextArea();
                    st.width = 50;
                    st.height = 50;
                    st.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onMouseDown);
                    st.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,onMouseUp);
                    rtw.width = 500;
                    rtw.height = 500;
                    rtw.addElement(st);
                    PopUpManager.addPopUp(rtw, this, false);
                    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(rtw);

            }

            private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                st.startDrag(true,new Rectangle(0,0,rtw.width,rtw.height));
            }

            private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                st.stopDrag();
            }
```

The above code will drag and drop textarea in popupView.

**Edit:**

To add event dynamic you can do like:

```
st.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_OVER,onlyAllowCopyDragOverHandler);
st.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_DROP,myComponent_dragDropHandler);
```